# I get error "Invalid File" when I open this demo page on android device in Firefox browser and choose file

Tags: ng-file-upload

On demo page of https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ for ng-file-upload component (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)
I get error "Invalid File" when I open this demo page on android device in Firefox browser (ver. 49.0.2) and choose file from android file system/gallery/camera !

In other Android browsers (Chrome, Opera) the image is uploaded succefully.

In windows desktop browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) the image is also uploaded succefully.

So the problem occurs only on android device in Firefox browser.

Can you check and tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: Possibly firefox android browser bug. When you do you the Invalid File error? In the console or popup?

Comment: Error is displayed right on demo page : https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ at bottom of page before the label: "How to upload to the server:" Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/7VEstwqRaqr3

Comment: Danial, no any idea?